# Having problems creating function that copies linked list while in template

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy

Assignment is to make a list of integers and functions that do various things. I finished all but one.

After I figured out how to make a function that searches the list for a specific value and node,  I have to make a function that duplicates said list. However, I'm having serious trouble doing this with the material I have right now.

This is the class I'm working with (T is the template)

```
    template <class T>
    class IntegerList{
    private:
    struct ListNode {
        T value;
        struct ListNode *next;
    };

    ListNode *head;
    public:
    //This is the constructor.
    IntegerList()
    {head = NULL;}

    //Destructor
    ~IntegerList();

    void appendNode(T);
    void insertNode(T);
    void deleteNode(T);
    void searchNode(T);
    void Duplicatenode(T);
    void displayList() const;
};
```

The functions so far:

```
//==appendNode definition==
template<class T>
void IntegerList<T>::appendNode(T newValue) {
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;

    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = newValue;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (!head) head = newNode;
    else {
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next)nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }

}

//==displayList Definition==
template<class T>
void IntegerList<T>::displayList() const {
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    nodePtr = head;

    while (nodePtr) {
        cout << nodePtr->value << "";
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//==insertNode Definiton==
template<class T>
void IntegerList<T>::insertNode(T newValue) {
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *previousNode = NULL;

    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = newValue;
    if (!head) {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr = head;
        previousNode = NULL;

        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value < newValue) {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (previousNode == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
        else {
            previousNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

//==deleteNode Definition==
template<class T>
void IntegerList<T>::deleteNode(T searchValue) {
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *previousNode = NULL;

    if (!head) return;
    if (head->value == searchValue) {
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != searchValue) {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (nodePtr) {
            previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

//searchNode Definiton
template <class T>
void IntegerList<T>::searchNode(T searchValue)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr=0;
    nodePtr = head;
    int i = searchValue;
                //This variable is initiated to remember the number to search for. For use in if statement.
    int j = 0;          
                //This variable is dedicated to the position number, starting with 0. Increments by 1 when the while loop loops.
        while (nodePtr)
        {
            if (i == nodePtr->value) {
                //This if statemtent will return a success message with the position number if the number is found.
                cout << "\nThe value "<< nodePtr->value <<" was found in the list, in position " << j <<" of this list.\n";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                j++;
            }
        }
        //This message only plays when it goes through the list without finding the value.
        cout << "\nThe value " << i << " was not found in this list.\n";
}

//==Duplicatenode Definition==
template<class T>
void IntegerList<T>::Duplicatenode(T)
{
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    ListNode* result = new ListNode;
    result->value = list->value;
    result->next = Clone(list->next);
    return result;
}



//==Destructor Definition==
template<class T>
IntegerList<T>::~IntegerList() {
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *nextNode;
    nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr != NULL) {
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nextNode;
    }
}
```

And the main function where testing happens.

```
int main() {
    IntegerList<int> list1;


    list1.appendNode(1);
    list1.appendNode(2);
    list1.appendNode(5);

    list1.displayList();
    list1.insertNode(4);

    list1.displayList();

    list1.deleteNode(2);
    list1.displayList();

    cout << "\nThis line breaks to denote searchNode function running.\n";

    list1.searchNode(5);
    list1.searchNode(3);

    cout << "\nLine break to denote copyNode function running.\n";

    IntegerList<int> list2(list1);
    list2.displayList();

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Searching around has not yielded me useful or usable answers. 
Is there a way I can do so while keeping with the template?

Comment: To duplicate a list, simply iterate over the existing list's nodes, and use the existing `insertNode()` to insert each value into the new list. That's it. Although your existing `insertNode()` isn't very efficient, as an introductory implementation it'll do.

Comment: That sounds like it would be relatively quick, but what commands should I put to denote which list would be which in the Duplicatenode function? For example, I want the duplicated list to be written to list2 from list1(the original list). How would the program know which link would be which?

Comment: The program will know because you will write the code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the provided source code, the way to duplicate the `list1` as the `list2` has not been completed.

**Analysis** - With the existing `class IntegerList`, the use of `IntegerList<int> list2(list1);` to duplicate will be only performed at data level. The class contains only one pointer data `ListNode *head;` and the default copying constructor will copy the `list1->head` into the `list2->head`.
The result is:

1. using `appendNode()` or `insertNode()` with the `list1` will add the same node into the `list2`,
2. using `deleteNode()` with the `list1` will remove the same node into the `list2`,
3. using `displayList()` with the `list2` will be the same as for the `list1`.

**Solution** - to perform the copy of the `list1` into the `list2` and allow to manage both lists independently, it is necessary to add your own copy-Constructor.

> In the `class IntegerList` declaration, append the copy-constructor. The source list is passed-by reference.

```
IntegerList(IntegerList& src);
```

Then add the copy-constructor implementation.

1. The destination `ListNode *head;` is initialize to `NULL` before starting the copy,
2. The source list is explored from `src.head` until `NULL` as in the `displayList()` function,
3. Each source node is add in the destination list using `appendNode()`,

The proposed copy-constructor:

```
template<class T>
IntegerList<T>::IntegerList(IntegerList& src) : head(NULL) {
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    nodePtr = src.head;

    while (nodePtr) {
        appendNode(nodePtr->value);
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}
```

> No change needed in the `main()` function. The use of
>   `IntegerList<int> list2(list1);` will automatically call the specific
>   copy-constructor instead of the default one.